# how to fit a muted sinusoidal curve to data python?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, curve, trigonometry

I have a data set of a muted oscillation, and want to fit it to and get out the vaules on the form `Ae^-(kt)*sin(cx+phase)+d`.

Any ideas how I can do that?

this is my data:

```
t = np.array([0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6000000000000001, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.5999999999999999, 1.7999999999999998, 1.9999999999999998, 2.1999999999999997, 2.4, 2.6, 2.8000000000000003, 3.0000000000000004, 3.2000000000000006, 3.400000000000001, 3.600000000000001, 3.800000000000001, 4.000000000000001, 4.200000000000001, 4.400000000000001, 4.600000000000001, 4.800000000000002, 5.000000000000002, 5.200000000000002, 5.400000000000002, 5.600000000000002, 5.8000000000000025, 6.000000000000003, 6.200000000000003, 6.400000000000003, 6.600000000000003, 6.800000000000003, 7.0000000000000036, 7.200000000000004, 7.400000000000004, 7.600000000000004, 7.800000000000004, 8.000000000000004, 8.200000000000003, 8.400000000000002, 8.600000000000001, 8.8, 9.0, 9.2, 9.399999999999999, 9.599999999999998, 9.799999999999997, 9.999999999999996, 10.199999999999996, 10.399999999999995, 10.599999999999994, 10.799999999999994, 10.999999999999993, 11.199999999999992, 11.399999999999991, 11.59999999999999, 11.79999999999999, 11.99999999999999, 12.199999999999989, 12.399999999999988, 12.599999999999987, 12.799999999999986, 12.999999999999986, 13.199999999999985, 13.399999999999984, 13.599999999999984, 13.799999999999983, 13.999999999999982, 14.199999999999982, 14.39999999999998, 14.59999999999998, 14.79999999999998, 14.999999999999979, 15.199999999999978, 15.399999999999977, 15.599999999999977, 15.799999999999976, 15.999999999999975, 16.199999999999974, 16.399999999999974, 16.599999999999973, 16.799999999999972, 16.99999999999997, 17.19999999999997, 17.39999999999997, 17.59999999999997, 17.79999999999997, 17.999999999999968, 18.199999999999967, 18.399999999999967, 18.599999999999966, 18.799999999999965, 18.999999999999964, 19.199999999999964, 19.399999999999963, 19.599999999999962, 19.79999999999996, 19.99999999999996, 20.19999999999996, 20.39999999999996, 20.59999999999996, 20.799999999999958, 20.999999999999957, 21.199999999999957, 21.399999999999956, 21.599999999999955, 21.799999999999955, 21.999999999999954, 22.199999999999953, 22.399999999999952, 22.59999999999995, 22.79999999999995, 22.99999999999995, 23.19999999999995, 23.39999999999995, 23.599999999999948, 23.799999999999947, 23.999999999999947, 24.199999999999946, 24.399999999999945, 24.599999999999945, 24.799999999999944, 24.999999999999943, 25.199999999999942, 25.39999999999994, 25.59999999999994, 25.79999999999994, 25.99999999999994, 26.19999999999994, 26.399999999999938, 26.599999999999937, 26.799999999999937, 26.999999999999936, 27.199999999999935, 27.399999999999935, 27.599999999999934, 27.799999999999933, 27.999999999999932, 28.199999999999932, 28.39999999999993, 28.59999999999993, 28.79999999999993, 28.99999999999993, 29.19999999999993, 29.399999999999928, 29.599999999999927, 29.799999999999926, 29.999999999999925, 30.199999999999925, 30.399999999999924, 30.599999999999923, 30.799999999999923, 30.999999999999922, 31.19999999999992, 31.39999999999992, 31.59999999999992, 31.79999999999992, 31.99999999999992, 32.19999999999992, 32.39999999999992, 32.59999999999992, 32.799999999999926, 32.99999999999993, 33.19999999999993, 33.399999999999935, 33.59999999999994, 33.79999999999994, 33.99999999999994, 34.199999999999946, 34.39999999999995, 34.59999999999995, 34.799999999999955, 34.99999999999996, 35.19999999999996, 35.39999999999996, 35.599999999999966, 35.79999999999997, 35.99999999999997, 36.199999999999974, 36.39999999999998, 36.59999999999998, 36.79999999999998, 36.999999999999986, 37.19999999999999, 37.39999999999999, 37.599999999999994, 37.8, 38.0, 38.2, 38.400000000000006, 38.60000000000001, 38.80000000000001, 39.000000000000014, 39.20000000000002, 39.40000000000002, 39.60000000000002, 39.800000000000026, 40.00000000000003, 40.20000000000003, 40.400000000000034, 40.60000000000004, 40.80000000000004, 41.00000000000004, 41.200000000000045, 41.40000000000005, 41.60000000000005, 41.800000000000054, 42.00000000000006, 42.20000000000006, 42.40000000000006, 42.600000000000065, 42.80000000000007, 43.00000000000007, 43.200000000000074, 43.40000000000008, 43.60000000000008, 43.80000000000008, 44.000000000000085, 44.20000000000009, 44.40000000000009, 44.600000000000094, 44.8000000000001, 45.0000000000001, 45.2000000000001, 45.400000000000105, 45.60000000000011, 45.80000000000011, 46.000000000000114, 46.20000000000012, 46.40000000000012, 46.60000000000012, 46.800000000000125, 47.00000000000013, 47.20000000000013, 47.400000000000134, 47.600000000000136, 47.80000000000014, 48.00000000000014, 48.200000000000145, 48.40000000000015, 48.60000000000015, 48.80000000000015, 49.000000000000156, 49.20000000000016, 49.40000000000016, 49.600000000000165, 49.80000000000017, 50.00000000000017, 50.20000000000017, 50.400000000000176, 50.60000000000018, 50.80000000000018, 51.000000000000185, 51.20000000000019, 51.40000000000019, 51.60000000000019, 51.800000000000196, 52.0000000000002, 52.2000000000002, 52.400000000000205, 52.60000000000021, 52.80000000000021, 53.00000000000021, 53.200000000000216, 53.40000000000022, 53.60000000000022, 53.800000000000225, 54.00000000000023, 54.20000000000023, 54.40000000000023, 54.600000000000236, 54.80000000000024, 55.00000000000024, 55.200000000000244, 55.40000000000025, 55.60000000000025, 55.80000000000025, 56.000000000000256, 56.20000000000026, 56.40000000000026, 56.600000000000264, 56.80000000000027, 57.00000000000027, 57.20000000000027, 57.400000000000276, 57.60000000000028, 57.80000000000028, 58.000000000000284, 58.20000000000029, 58.40000000000029, 58.60000000000029, 58.800000000000296, 59.0000000000003, 59.2000000000003, 59.400000000000304, 59.60000000000031, 59.80000000000031, 60.00000000000031, 60.200000000000315, 60.40000000000032, 60.60000000000032, 60.800000000000324, 61.00000000000033, 61.20000000000033, 61.40000000000033, 61.600000000000335, 61.80000000000034, 62.00000000000034, 62.200000000000344, 62.40000000000035, 62.60000000000035, 62.80000000000035, 63.000000000000355, 63.20000000000036, 63.40000000000036, 63.600000000000364, 63.80000000000037, 64.00000000000037, 64.20000000000037, 64.40000000000038, 64.60000000000038, 64.80000000000038, 65.00000000000038, 65.20000000000039, 65.40000000000039, 65.60000000000039, 65.8000000000004, 66.0000000000004, 66.2000000000004, 66.4000000000004, 66.6000000000004, 66.80000000000041, 67.00000000000041, 67.20000000000041, 67.40000000000042, 67.60000000000042, 67.80000000000042, 68.00000000000043, 68.20000000000043, 68.40000000000043, 68.60000000000043, 68.80000000000044, 69.00000000000044, 69.20000000000044, 69.40000000000045, 69.60000000000045, 69.80000000000045, 70.00000000000045, 70.20000000000046, 70.40000000000046, 70.60000000000046, 70.80000000000047, 71.00000000000047, 71.20000000000047, 71.40000000000047, 71.60000000000048, 71.80000000000048, 72.00000000000048, 72.20000000000049, 72.40000000000049, 72.60000000000049, 72.8000000000005, 73.0000000000005, 73.2000000000005, 73.4000000000005, 73.6000000000005, 73.80000000000051, 74.00000000000051, 74.20000000000051, 74.40000000000052, 74.60000000000052, 74.80000000000052, 75.00000000000053, 75.20000000000053, 75.40000000000053, 75.60000000000053, 75.80000000000054, 76.00000000000054, 76.20000000000054, 76.40000000000055, 76.60000000000055, 76.80000000000055, 77.00000000000055, 77.20000000000056, 77.40000000000056, 77.60000000000056, 77.80000000000057, 78.00000000000057, 78.20000000000057, 78.40000000000057, 78.60000000000058, 78.80000000000058, 79.00000000000058, 79.20000000000059, 79.40000000000059, 79.60000000000059, 79.8000000000006, 80.0000000000006, 80.2000000000006, 80.4000000000006, 80.6000000000006, 80.80000000000061, 81.00000000000061, 81.20000000000061, 81.40000000000062, 81.60000000000062, 81.80000000000062, 82.00000000000063, 82.20000000000063, 82.40000000000063, 82.60000000000063, 82.80000000000064, 83.00000000000064, 83.20000000000064, 83.40000000000065, 83.60000000000065, 83.80000000000065, 84.00000000000065, 84.20000000000066, 84.40000000000066, 84.60000000000066, 84.80000000000067, 85.00000000000067, 85.20000000000067, 85.40000000000067, 85.60000000000068, 85.80000000000068, 86.00000000000068, 86.20000000000068, 86.40000000000069, 86.60000000000069, 86.8000000000007, 87.0000000000007, 87.2000000000007, 87.4000000000007, 87.6000000000007, 87.80000000000071, 88.00000000000071, 88.20000000000071, 88.40000000000072, 88.60000000000072, 88.80000000000072, 89.00000000000072, 89.20000000000073, 89.40000000000073, 89.60000000000073, 89.80000000000074, 90.00000000000074, 90.20000000000074, 90.40000000000074, 90.60000000000075, 90.80000000000075, 91.00000000000075, 91.20000000000076, 91.40000000000076, 91.60000000000076, 91.80000000000076, 92.00000000000077, 92.20000000000077, 92.40000000000077, 92.60000000000078, 92.80000000000078, 93.00000000000078, 93.20000000000078, 93.40000000000079, 93.60000000000079, 93.8000000000008, 94.0000000000008, 94.2000000000008, 94.4000000000008, 94.6000000000008, 94.80000000000081, 95.00000000000081, 95.20000000000081, 95.40000000000082, 95.60000000000082, 95.80000000000082, 96.00000000000082, 96.20000000000083, 96.40000000000083, 96.60000000000083, 96.80000000000084, 97.00000000000084, 97.20000000000084, 97.40000000000084, 97.60000000000085, 97.80000000000085, 98.00000000000085, 98.20000000000086, 98.40000000000086, 98.60000000000086, 98.80000000000086, 99.00000000000087, 99.20000000000087, 99.40000000000087, 99.60000000000088, 99.80000000000088, 100.00000000000088, 100.20000000000088, 100.40000000000089, 100.60000000000089, 100.80000000000089, 101.0000000000009, 101.2000000000009, 101.4000000000009, 101.6000000000009, 101.8000000000009, 102.00000000000091, 102.20000000000091, 102.40000000000092, 102.60000000000092, 102.80000000000092, 103.00000000000092, 103.20000000000093, 103.40000000000093, 103.60000000000093, 103.80000000000094, 104.00000000000094, 104.20000000000094, 104.40000000000094, 104.60000000000095, 104.80000000000095, 105.00000000000095, 105.20000000000095, 105.40000000000096, 105.60000000000096, 105.80000000000096, 106.00000000000097, 106.20000000000097, 106.40000000000097, 106.60000000000097, 106.80000000000098, 107.00000000000098, 107.20000000000098, 107.40000000000099, 107.60000000000099, 107.80000000000099, 108.000000000001, 108.200000000001, 108.400000000001, 108.600000000001, 108.800000000001, 109.00000000000101, 109.20000000000101, 109.40000000000101, 109.60000000000102, 109.80000000000102, 110.00000000000102, 110.20000000000103, 110.40000000000103, 110.60000000000103, 110.80000000000103, 111.00000000000104, 111.20000000000104, 111.40000000000104, 111.60000000000105, 111.80000000000105, 112.00000000000105, 112.20000000000105, 112.40000000000106, 112.60000000000106, 112.80000000000106, 113.00000000000107, 113.20000000000107, 113.40000000000107, 113.60000000000107, 113.80000000000108, 114.00000000000108, 114.20000000000108, 114.40000000000109, 114.60000000000109, 114.80000000000109, 115.0000000000011, 115.2000000000011, 115.4000000000011, 115.6000000000011, 115.8000000000011, 116.00000000000111, 116.20000000000111, 116.40000000000111, 116.60000000000112, 116.80000000000112, 117.00000000000112, 117.20000000000113, 117.40000000000113, 117.60000000000113, 117.80000000000113, 118.00000000000114, 118.20000000000114, 118.40000000000114, 118.60000000000115, 118.80000000000115, 119.00000000000115, 119.20000000000115, 119.40000000000116, 119.60000000000116, 119.80000000000116, 120.00000000000117, 120.20000000000117, 120.40000000000117, 120.60000000000117, 120.80000000000118, 121.00000000000118, 121.20000000000118, 121.40000000000119, 121.60000000000119, 121.80000000000119, 122.0000000000012, 122.2000000000012, 122.4000000000012, 122.6000000000012, 122.8000000000012, 123.00000000000121, 123.20000000000121, 123.40000000000121, 123.60000000000122, 123.80000000000122, 124.00000000000122, 124.20000000000122, 124.40000000000123, 124.60000000000123, 124.80000000000123, 125.00000000000124, 125.20000000000124, 125.40000000000124, 125.60000000000124, 125.80000000000125, 126.00000000000125, 126.20000000000125, 126.40000000000126, 126.60000000000126, 126.80000000000126, 127.00000000000126, 127.20000000000127, 127.40000000000127, 127.60000000000127, 127.80000000000128, 128.00000000000128, 128.20000000000127, 128.40000000000126, 128.60000000000124, 128.80000000000123, 129.00000000000122, 129.2000000000012, 129.4000000000012, 129.6000000000012, 129.80000000000118, 130.00000000000117, 130.20000000000115, 130.40000000000114, 130.60000000000113, 130.80000000000112, 131.0000000000011, 131.2000000000011, 131.40000000000109, 131.60000000000107, 131.80000000000106, 132.00000000000105, 132.20000000000104, 132.40000000000103, 132.60000000000102, 132.800000000001, 133.000000000001, 133.20000000000098, 133.40000000000097, 133.60000000000096, 133.80000000000095, 134.00000000000094, 134.20000000000093, 134.40000000000092, 134.6000000000009, 134.8000000000009, 135.00000000000088, 135.20000000000087, 135.40000000000086, 135.60000000000085, 135.80000000000084, 136.00000000000082, 136.2000000000008, 136.4000000000008, 136.6000000000008, 136.80000000000078, 137.00000000000077, 137.20000000000076, 137.40000000000074, 137.60000000000073, 137.80000000000072, 138.0000000000007, 138.2000000000007, 138.4000000000007, 138.60000000000068, 138.80000000000067, 139.00000000000065, 139.20000000000064, 139.40000000000063, 139.60000000000062, 139.8000000000006, 140.0000000000006, 140.20000000000059, 140.40000000000057, 140.60000000000056, 140.80000000000055, 141.00000000000054, 141.20000000000053, 141.40000000000052, 141.6000000000005, 141.8000000000005, 142.00000000000048, 142.20000000000047, 142.40000000000046, 142.60000000000045, 142.80000000000044, 143.00000000000043, 143.20000000000041, 143.4000000000004, 143.6000000000004, 143.80000000000038, 144.00000000000037, 144.20000000000036, 144.40000000000035, 144.60000000000034, 144.80000000000032, 145.0000000000003, 145.2000000000003, 145.4000000000003, 145.60000000000028, 145.80000000000027, 146.00000000000026, 146.20000000000024, 146.40000000000023, 146.60000000000022, 146.8000000000002, 147.0000000000002, 147.2000000000002, 147.40000000000018, 147.60000000000016, 147.80000000000015, 148.00000000000014, 148.20000000000013, 148.40000000000012, 148.6000000000001, 148.8000000000001, 149.00000000000009, 149.20000000000007, 149.40000000000006, 149.60000000000005, 149.80000000000004, 150.00000000000003, 150.20000000000002, 150.4, 150.6, 150.79999999999998])

data = np.array([-17.895166829633922, -7.850310582296288, -10.400080032016035, -12.555264688814987, -14.875887137689688, -17.403405204309593, -9.384189611217494, -4.8134501496749635, -11.288830542083133, -11.008508544742426, -11.008508544742426, -24.399675324728832, -11.801622922577621, -11.553206224788369, -6.85295195569654, 7.054570807289565, 59.28761332019553, 294.39871205088207, 238.80102498356405, 107.75489263075929, 56.92080305897116, -17.532368285997904, -134.43846589745613, -223.57517841817833, -278.0, -323.0007278024234, -321.8488538118969, -307.68383188196503, -254.07407770337704, -164.82546181276848, -80.251646949563, 130.4490343719881, 212.22747473618847, 274.903109187615, 306.2431386335884, 335.63590915224904, 314.16917348199877, 200.52715789444392, 113.2666646883099, 24.431244694397265, -75.25725464168488, -162.69840080405845, -224.60328495721353, -332.20357038414545, -337.45260390066187, -320.4436208691852, -266.3334080382526, -205.55236341947034, -112.4210341145465, 73.40943322457747, 162.27300574567516, 236.84561995461172, 276.76959864616015, 310.3696452130366, 293.9325135910983, 223.85574521497438, 156.265835905348, 76.00552484782497, -15.213590764328956, -110.83594377888971, -192.69711856619517, -303.31195000905814, -331.89676302203065, -319.0296677859461, -287.8587395806828, -233.15509913496885, -164.83492736625703, -67.45875421815094, 23.37118210253948, 187.06975569513065, 248.12558991541073, 287.5854499800773, 301.7621735665348, 280.519275330671, 233.45968973666368, 111.64165400541356, 26.941656989437433, -60.88672962601561, -145.48163697929465, -213.9598000100749, -266.67772803446826, -302.39559074296324, -293.72072485656827, -250.031579603468, -183.2279637046255, -115.92170365230322, -22.882985659754695, 138.31354603174486, 208.54995794181536, 260.57782130808505, 290.0615370050757, 270.0687481537857, 259.0657981365662, 141.19416259812579, 61.17878993191425, -19.60613895279016, -96.13348896023115, -177.67314112783788, -276.2098392592062, -296.73146711774814, -290.4112285478601, -261.0060080347773, -210.10000625078135, -159.49426809691636, 11.77884104144573, 83.47153598070395, 161.51525811659826, 219.3152565554533, 256.2069341146414, 277.43465853611383, 229.30302993255054, 176.12646880507646, 99.854044458099, 25.75286627650712, -55.33147113775658, -133.13284928673488, -246.0314142584134, -274.20655072228317, -277.96721384899706, -267.72242388712834, -230.3693182025222, -190.19514517173047, -33.844274718423776, 32.17464947099916, 111.67731545217589, 172.6005242684446, 226.465931596985, 257.5014792890777, 249.70790265045184, 196.61510018729678, 140.9509112034275, 71.42868465747665, -3.238856530507519, -156.2365667235449, -217.74751499285276, -246.20945279481236, -265.9462385015448, -269.8918997876053, -245.61266363184689, -143.74368689169137, -77.51085797206201, 5.795254960368425, 74.05903898265615, 147.35560654450546, 196.51564432459804, 253.72781879643685, 234.7393301410541, 204.92715831032433, 164.40027247953253, 103.68218087567516, 33.30244895715646, -120.50576168251655, -175.75303416793895, -227.6241312514809, -254.48692929903586, -259.36293723264635, -244.44138042864415, -170.13334391702392, -104.11700534782085, -38.95520185729845, 48.821986926981026, 96.6200793406922, 159.16380375035556, 223.85574521497438, 238.6472680465049, 180.80476989303338, 122.97484526356538, 71.36950206670804, -71.41382920905983, -140.96835500656255, -193.7353370382864, -236.49886877910774, -256.5970533638722, -250.27373350660037, -191.9242088901542, -142.58083950145533, -71.95096077017377, -9.160352503958848, 72.72988321187472, 131.29750722587664, 209.90819326701785, 222.006493489381, 223.64824808370713, 200.52715789444392, 146.92004909587422, 94.81853713630267, -34.94307858463981, -111.17409917159148, -153.27133817059678, -203.9925558656421, -227.6241312514809, -248.38067251414896, -198.64064681548166, -168.8674301871315, -112.02895369616738, -36.996402884346935, 33.30244895715646, 87.82330090046821, 177.95286101764145, 208.06403772543922, 205.37483929855966, 201.85477677814174, 164.4070844472967, 124.97136527755629, 6.20470378757841, -61.78061610194868, -124.038375548918, -176.1175142743433, -204.0223328156046, -226.61248414338388, -201.36658491007188, -173.39734640631218, -131.03697461155969, -74.76954711686165, -8.864644516037515, 54.75161422746851, 157.8424551282592, 184.13902038246783, 205.87499357458614, 184.98953970317257, 167.7537943050745, 138.31354603174486, 35.44727270197609, -39.77116101406261, -89.43495612748802, -135.32520328981695, -182.2705756106045, -212.38355082157443, -211.56152397319931, -184.6322031966597, -151.8997727537884, -102.54641992000495, -46.713957331468464, 20.681328054408823, 122.76299374582322, 171.03005888927305, 185.2238284103944, 184.13902038246783, 173.9662157342159, 144.69822897586528, 54.676476682001294, 2.916580968047924, -56.42147675191427, -104.11700534782085, -156.18034691159744, -182.8796943612133, -205.56230819285952, -192.25676401452267, -160.82157351943988, -117.8565137826763, -67.56061202855062, -11.040541363164266, 85.10182174992292, 141.18721327158596, 169.95254141850978, 183.65656702420074, 168.84010790267916, 153.55317884486908, 81.33312970879797, 30.35378597859676, -25.471686542230486, -76.42193684727147, -129.14586905662975, -173.6173124699436, -192.5013761479472, -186.01941770451901, -168.59165680390356, -139.2761631837567, -96.93921341457224, -41.37210446942015, 60.6484016706886, 108.42031455083998, 135.83768484022198, 159.97777756673645, 165.1153134905528, 156.5333257134148, 99.04643726040626, 52.95437343283925, 5.346246361308999, -42.68619362690788, -96.93921341457224, -137.76150050573892, -183.63446344852935, -187.3895210976218, -169.40973120074727, -142.40562473008163, -109.21811741132365, -62.514907768992884, 37.274558079207736, 81.33312970879797, 110.09999553611283, 135.36980927558943, 152.21856808433404, 150.04137857233354, 106.5804941874992, 72.4786372026008, 29.038016628843025, -14.803536983777235, -69.30238652370338, -121.62170220114001, -173.4451601956988, -178.76958669692556, -175.18744618926576, -148.4293412609735, -124.48094317513414, -78.33482409183068, 6.259809300751613, 53.65407910654858, 89.10509051682584, 131.59887876609264, 143.14526404959065, 142.25691579612567, 111.6701832535266, 84.67072674845917, 51.003298769612684, 10.43912116304125, -40.538293690771866, -88.6010635994852, -154.39261340261908, -165.65883672534358, -174.76590107922436, -157.2397757868863, -136.41428583109257, -103.89625318068568, -17.218050123794796, 31.683253201279058, 61.17878993191425, 103.06423893681904, 131.0241014106582, 143.12445121938163, 123.22195531149146, 99.04643726040626, 66.92896701685959, 30.63057806312804, -12.35477247670849, -63.93446315807489, -137.10138045704298, -151.45238920604993, -159.94588407560786, -157.2397757868863, -140.64621700943871, -121.07255639169296, -48.90062948725222, 0.5127411368943058, 41.66534601079252, 75.13593618495565, 99.91891595737752, 128.06150976122558, 111.43479525115504, 103.06423893681904, 81.58966649561125, 40.78256551962272, 0.2593726365521434, -35.435481868952934, -110.0533349136739, -132.90479422128863, -139.2761631837567, -145.52790675464837, -140.41619150308463, -117.8565137826763, -55.80924338998125, -13.71088533498471, 18.832347858483672, 54.52618568074695, 82.65914172719022, 104.14182221115811, 107.9051838147991, 102.57539070392886, 79.99816513607038, 54.29319268705285, 18.622379690428488, -17.693595707454847, -90.78294184670403, -108.99611543567698, -127.78460679945056, -140.1678322802726, -131.5468139963291, -124.038375548918, -68.63928274013904, -38.05761487627262, -0.5803647639897918, 34.612846943785144, 67.65671714140944, 90.18907465944244, 106.37986366648511, 97.50891644266221, 94.60852794100765, 65.58356253710008, 40.78256551962272, 1.3357503816425833, -66.01694930470285, -91.03536520712612, -115.59964221831842, -121.72977084673153, -114.66989327957924, -103.47255970930473, -74.88075626688124, -47.81914381962474, -17.919358116488638, 21.534778861091127, 39.21303842451357, 100.14233321678171, 98.80836937678282, 96.38148936069956, 83.99817184490757, 70.03703640199296, 50.52062686210866, 18.886777055668063, -50.95047051781523, -79.97634438687533, -89.68700976243952, -112.75978690208046, -116.38710841886348, -111.17409917159148, -99.56274241439348, -64.44196370608745, -35.65714453278815, -4.5985876278072055, 19.55524378247901, 49.10150599458598, 74.05903898265615, 90.29814141440784, 86.1824665629349, 69.79257267310368, 62.26862306047178, 22.596726704089406, -10.14401036949323, -55.80085935901195, -75.70240287154752, -101.18098611439689, -113.80359295520498, -100.6881722973136, -92.7257770982551, -69.5490443409609, -43.174265961026435, -12.611409730389937, 9.372355913186425, 43.88424411792016, 70.29625566323239, 85.1091269823296, 72.4786372026008, 77.32331898106554, 62.03731278346845, 36.78555588047743, -13.197110758601411, -32.93500727945434, -66.58492698070586, -80.57006719172205, -96.79027600446568, -104.92983697395039, -88.34930694975333, -73.30794814944647, -60.44010194195755, -32.247475073574606, -1.8650883934234344, 21.496000961710024, 62.26862306047178, 68.23559577672995, 80.24034047543842, 63.88639995113067, 62.03731278346845, 41.901136038934055, 3.1771809510911453, -31.184389172301735, -43.174265961026435, -66.83087412702059, -82.17242981252173, -86.94420537001122, -78.4121082796321, -73.30794814944647, -65.27993564230894, -39.41667024412584, -26.78893415503103, 2.142282487990883, 46.74973385376347, 61.440152318364426, 63.37970914304128, 65.47942797619339, 57.168215418731506, 44.54445141018118, 12.037181319740398, -6.19125327580457, -40.761123355031714, -52.92111087956812, -72.43720210324045, -80.57006719172205, -80.19141754875159, -75.93362120243296, -60.684457095534526, -49.625073213591236, -35.19745589170725, -9.440156712253383, 38.37397907426157, 47.24169422133559, 57.168215418731506, 59.85606508539263, 46.74973385376347, 36.56390153683401, 17.727590366240975, -0.6279179608740151, -17.032729643116568, -38.32104067238345, -53.38931638832298, -63.79072082334767, -73.53857527391983, -76.14776329442782, -57.15163850694478, -56.42147675191427, -26.33338981136501, -11.737509469578413, 12.639721505086072, 36.56390153683401, 45.65145763173177, 52.32198508738384, 39.92952144417768, 43.46665822891623, 18.622379690428488, 2.6717138342514772, -15.285970743349822, -27.578501863889414, -37.341786648567904, -55.80085935901195, -64.44196370608745, -62.464248695596666, -63.10613055105273, -48.06029294970881, -43.80333264909257, -17.218050123794796, 1.3357503816425833, 23.06146961349782, 29.53066332840808, 39.44937943666446, 35.22533455709913, 28.41417555809585, 19.55524378247901, 8.869962262113177, -5.076122285871861, -19.048941672697993, -27.676224455500574, -52.252642916724085, -55.33147113775658, -59.08465150677057, -53.79081786462643, -48.06029294970881, -43.174265961026435, -14.369546468168778, -6.19125327580457, 6.432978607050131, 25.513399237305748, 31.683253201279058, 31.683253201279058, 31.122471181945002, 23.06146961349782, 17.727590366240975, 6.432978607050131, -8.832681316454455, -22.810048673508845, -39.16942775786049, -50.483455067084265, -48.06029294970881, -51.15903299869376, -40.538293690771866, -39.77116101406261, -36.05133605512867, -7.012462689590507, -1.9206380448015352, 6.432978607050131, 13.734340539575783, 28.159910611077294, 23.936168242508074, 18.22565616697193, 0.013861291022067235, 0.7977047856805939, -9.072430192873526, -17.177760120171342, -31.67490065929519, -34.67236274162724, -44.06004327391031, -41.09133557388395, -32.51751933858168, -37.59679144914378, -23.60454177850147, -16.340098424013036, -4.845285540579084, 4.873391118320683, 6.165340877162521, 10.43912116304125, 15.795301217548058, 16.411223633101145, 8.430164517921185, 2.4425909650383346, -7.523067597064369, -6.4223996122671, -16.380354461527418, -21.6761664312653, -31.184389172301735, -45.63492390070451, -17.46788465057716, -21.457638742779977, -27.676224455500574, -16.340098424013036, -11.841695921934388, -5.490169286532023, -5.299049467952386, 3.1771809510911453, 2.6717138342514772, -0.8419350765708487, -2.1825562136762073, -0.5803647639897918, -2.658945540290233, -15.857153121343458, -12.35477247670849, -21.70045026823982, -17.46788465057716, -23.39369554011057, -23.0288758023363, -21.457638742779977, -23.912782762092547, -17.46788465057716, -10.18401693111548, -11.288830542083133, -8.840672020681836, -3.755496909424096, -12.587347182721942, -6.4223996122671, -6.4223996122671, -5.944224656817141, -10.18401693111548, -7.754521087772673, -4.5985876278072055, -16.95216630818834, -19.266938070602237, -8.600978630396298, -18.814850797289182, -22.51835460095765, -12.35477247670849, -16.380354461527418, -13.461992696716038, -11.288830542083133, -11.737509469578413, -7.275710875616596, -11.288830542083133, -16.831333559097857, -9.072430192873526, -7.754521087772673, -9.952001151944728, -9.048452721111971, -9.952001151944728, -14.538298074707427, -13.919681953307531, -0.4297944174461463, -4.336040220193581, -11.288830542083133, -11.288830542083133, -11.521156959247378, -13.943776687279524, -15.052765218174954, -13.461992696716038, -9.072430192873526, -15.052765218174954, -11.937877684960881, -1.317691242678734, -11.288830542083133, -2.658945540290233, -13.197110758601411, -9.952001151944728, -8.329395459764896, -12.362791391580117, -9.440156712253383, -8.832681316454455, -12.611409730389937, -11.288830542083133, -4.845285540579084, -22.575066144266316, -15.285970743349822, -13.197110758601411, -18.564676844727273, -8.600978630396298, -3.9860835952615616, -16.831333559097857, -6.19125327580457, -9.072430192873526, -10.18401693111548, -13.71088533498471, -8.353355718694615, -11.040541363164266, -13.197110758601411, -12.84404429397307, -12.587347182721942, -13.943776687279524, -8.600978630396298, -6.4223996122671, -18.814850797289182, -15.285970743349822, -13.197110758601411, -13.461992696716038, -15.285970743349822, -6.4223996122671, -18.814850797289182, -14.803536983777235, -8.832681316454455, -8.353355718694615, -11.288830542083133, -9.704043795037592, -9.952001151944728, -11.040541363164266, -7.754521087772673, -11.521156959247378, -6.4223996122671, -3.755496909424096, -13.71088533498471, -20.381891839079117, -9.704043795037592, -12.106218077294557, -2.658945540290233, -6.119529027484305, -9.704043795037592, -15.285970743349822, -17.919358116488638, -13.197110758601411, -12.106218077294557, -16.1307933133254, -13.71088533498471, -12.611409730389937, -16.106645559997673, -7.523067597064369, -13.670737155632878, -11.040541363164266, -16.1307933133254, -12.362791391580117, -15.285970743349822, -16.380354461527418, -16.61387164909536, -12.587347182721942, -12.362791391580117, -12.84404429397307, -16.380354461527418, -9.952001151944728, -11.040541363164266, -9.952001151944728, -14.538298074707427, -13.197110758601411, -13.461992696716038, -9.704043795037592, -3.9860835952615616, -5.944224656817141, -11.521156959247378, -16.61387164909536, -17.177760120171342, -11.521156959247378, -7.275710875616596, -9.952001151944728, -3.9860835952615616, -8.832681316454455, -13.943776687279524])
```

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the first 30 data points, I see:

[image: first_30]

so I removed the non-sine-wave part of the data. I also realized it is much easier to fit a sine wave to the first few cycles to give me some of the parameters, such as:

```
y = amplitude * sin(pi * (x - center) / width) + Offset

amplitude =  3.3098923173806202E+02
center =  2.1702445745645457E+02
width =  1.8508302910055434E+00
Offset = -9.6083629945476581E+00
```

[image: few_cycles]

rather than the entire data set. Now I can plug those parameters back in to the exponential decay equation as constants (or initial parameter estimates), and solve for the exponential decay using all data.